# Unexpected duplication of :after pseudo element assigned to SVG:text. Working with pseudo elements and SVG

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, pseudo-element

This is a two-part question, see below.

While trying to add a % symbol via CSS to an instance of SVG text using the :after pseudo-element I ran into this problem ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74mP2/) provided). I am on Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57.

HTML:

```
<span class="percentage2">This is 20</span>
<p class="percentage2">This is 20</p>
<h1 class="percentage2">This is 20</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <text x="20" y="20" style="fill:black;" class="percentage2">This is 20</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.percentage2:after {
    content:"%";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
}
```

The unexpected result is that the % symbol appears twice: once at the leftmost edge of the wrapper element and once where it was supposed to be positioned.

[image]

**First question**: why is this happening?

If I do not specify a display:inline-block the :after content is inserted as inline in the HTML elements, but does not appear in the SVG.

CSS:

```
.percentage1:after {
    content:"%";
    font-size:0.7em;
}
```

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

**Second question**: is there a way to add inline pseudo elements to an SVG text element? What other display modes are supported when applying :after elements to SVG elements?

Comment: I don't think SVG supports `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements. I'm surprised they even appear, though I can't find any reference that confirms that they are not supported. Hopefully someone with more knowledge will chime in.

Comment: They aren't defined in the SVG specification and aren't supported by Firefox.

Comment: Would the fact that they are not defined imply that applying them will result in unexpected behavior?

Comment: Looks that way in Chrome doesn't it? In Firefox we deliberately disabled them to prevent such weirdness.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll validate any answer that mentions current support or lack thereof across common browsers.

Comment: Seems there have not been any activity on this post for the last 2 years. I've come across this issue and would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Duopixel wrote, SVG doesn't support CSS `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements applied to svg elements. SVG might allow this in the future, but how that should work is still not defined.

Comment: It could be fun (or not) to see what other side effects can turn up in other browsers apart from Chrome.