# svg css animation without stroke

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to make a hamburger menu with svg, but my problem is that my svg is only a fill, without stroke.

How can I change the size of each line on hover ?

Here is the svg:

```html
<svg id="menu" x="0px" y="0px" width="64.948px" height="30.172px" viewBox="0 0 64.948 30.172" style="enable-background:new 0 0 64.948 30.172;" xml:space="preserve">

  <style type="text/css">
    .st1{
      fill:#CE0011;
   transition:all .8s ease;
    }
  </style>

  <path class="st1" id="line1" d="M64.948,2.73c-1.098,3.107-2.33,4.997-6.812,4.952c-16.91-0.17-33.824-0.068-50.942-0.068 c0.401-3.24,1.888-4.961,6.324-4.931C30.436,2.8,47.357,2.73,64.948,2.73z"/>
  <path class="st1" id="line2" d="M60.676,12.856c-0.947,2.002-1.688,3.567-2.365,4.999c-18.135,0-36.122,0-54.159,0 c0.843-4.768,1.126-4.995,6.183-4.997c15.25-0.006,30.499-0.002,45.749-0.002C57.404,12.856,58.723,12.856,60.676,12.856z"/>
  <path class="st1" id="line3" d="M56.599,23.023c-0.459,4.176-2.703,5.04-6.567,4.994C33.458,27.817,16.88,27.932,0,27.932 c0.348-2.549,0.455-4.888,3.908-4.894C21.379,23.006,38.849,23.023,56.599,23.023z"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: You can do something like this `svg:hover .st1{ transform: scale(0.8)}`

Comment: ok but is it possible to add a ::before and ::after fonction on each line ? for example svg:hover #line1::before ???

Comment: SVG does not support :after and :before pseudo-elements.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15005566)

Answer (score 0):

As aspsmn said, try ...

```
svg:hover .st1 {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

I built a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/pv0np9pw/) to test this and actually tried with a scale up to 1.2 ... this became an issue since I hadn't changed the size of the viewbox.

However, this did prove the working concept.